# proj4.js how can I convert UTM to EOV coordinate?

Tags: utm, proj4js

I using javascript for converting UTM to WSG84 lon lat with the following code where the utm_zone contains the UTM zone number.

```
var utm = "+proj=utm +zone=";
utm = utm + "" + utm_zone;
var wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
var lonlatArray = proj4(utm, wgs84, [utm_x, utm_y]);
```

But how can I parameterize for convert directly the UTM format to EOV (epsg:23700)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of EOV / EPSG:23700 from https://epsg.io/23700.

Example:

```
var utm = "+proj=utm +zone=34T";
var epsg23700 = '+proj=somerc +lat_0=47.14439372222222 +lon_0=19.04857177777778 +k_0=0.99993 +x_0=650000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=GRS67 +towgs84=52.17,-71.82,-14.9,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs';
console.log(proj4(utm, epsg23700, [352920, 5263357]));
```